# Unable to center the text in Toolbar title

Tags: android

Here is the image : [image]

I have used a `textview` inside the `toolbar` and tried to center the `textview` using `gravity="center"`. I want to center the `textview` without using `margin shifts` or `padding shifts` or `translationX`.

```
           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:title="Train App"
                app:collapseIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/appTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Train App"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mood_white_24dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/bounds_m"
        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/appname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And about **ic_mood_white_24dp** just go with option menu instead of putting it in toolbar.

Comment: Thanks I was able to center the text but the text along with hamburger menu vanishes when AppBarLayout is collapsed because they do not come inside Toolbar

Comment: If you place TextView inside Toolbar, area that can be used for "title" is decreased by hamburger view size. In that case add right margin to your TextView to center it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/appTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Train App"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` property in your `TextView`.

**Like :**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/appTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Train App"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```